# Do I always need a local folder to reflect a git repo (on github)?

Tags: git

I am very much a beginner using git and I am trying to understand it. Do I always need to set up a local folder that will reflect the git repo hosted on github.com? Is it possible to work directly on the git repo itself? Excuse my general ignorance on the matter.

Comment: The simple answer is yes, but the setup is almost invisible as `git clone` will come naturally to you over time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, literally "working directly on the repo" on Github would require you to have filesystem access (via SCP, FTP, or a similar protocol). For reasons of both management and security, this is not implemented (not to mention it's not along the mindset of how Git works).

By "working directly on the repo" you might also mean something like [SVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion), [CVS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System) or other centralized version control systems, in which you only have a local *working copy*, not a copy of the complete repo.
This is not technically possible with Git (or if it were implemented, would cause many technical problems afterward).

Git is a [*distributed version control system* (DVCS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control) and one of the core concepts of such systems is that every client has the complete history of a repo.
While this means that you intially have to download a larger chunk of data than with centralized repositories (sometimes, at least), it offers a number of advantages. For example, almost all of your repository actions are local, making them much faster (if your client doesn't have to send new commit data over the network right away, the commit takes only a fraction of a second instead of 30 seconds or more).

Therefore, **yes, you must have a local clone** to work on files in a Git/Github repository. Note that you can also make local repositories which are not on Github (of course, other people can't get those files directly then), and conversely you don't *have* to have a clone of your repo -- but then you can't change the contents of the repo ;)

Comment: @andrew-welch, it should be noted that if absolutely necessary, it's possible to perform the so-called "shallow cloning", fetching only a minimal amount of history from the remote, for a given branch. *But* this is not a normal course of operation with Git, and should only be employed in special cases, and one should understand well what limitations this infers.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using Git, you need to make the changes locally before you push them up to your remote (eg. Github). This is because Git is a "Distributed Version Control System", or DVCS. It is distributed because everyone who is working on the project has a copy of the repository. There are a few reasons why people may use a DVCS such as:

1. You are working offline for a while; and
2. You want to test changes that you make to project locally before you push those changes onto everyone's local repositories (this reducing the chance of introducing bugs)

These are just a couple of reasons why many people prefer to use a DVCS instead of a centralized counterpart (like Subversion).

## Short answer:

No, you cannot directly edit your remote files when using Git. Even though Github provides this feature for single files, it's purely for minor changes that you want to make on the fly. **Edit your files locally, then push them to a remote**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you always need to set up a local folder.  Git is a [distributed version control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_version_control_system), which by definition requires a local copy of the repository.

Its important to realize that there is nothing special about the GitHub repository itself.  Fundamentally, its the same as your local copy.

Git leverages a peer to peer architecture, as opposed to CVS or SVN which use a client-server architecture.

As an aside, GitHub does support editing files directly via their web interface.

Comment: While that is true, it is still possible to work directly with the remote repo if it is accessible via ssh, in that case it is just a local repo.

Comment: @prusswan Agreed. However the question specifically mentions a repo hosted on GitHub, where ssh access will be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to clone the remote repository to your local machine in order to work with it.

`git clone` will do this for you (if not otherwise specified).